# How to determine actual font size using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

If my font-size is set to be X-Large and I want to test how many pixels that is on a particular browser using Selenium WebDriver. How would I do that?

The idea is to check if the font size falls within a particular range of allowed font-sizes for our window size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do that is getting the font-size from the styles, e.g.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("xxx")).getCssValue("font-size");
```

And then, based on this information you could calculate the size by following this article:
http://www.erinsowards.com/articles/2010/01/calculating-font-sizes.php

Comment: Yes, the above code works for me very well. Thanks Sergio Cazzolato